# SharePoint Server 2019 Alternate Access Mapping Internet Access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, site-collection, alternate-access-mapping

I have a SharePoint site that I want to put it on an AAM for Internet access. Things works fine when I put it on a subdomain URL (e.g. sub.domain.com) and I am able to access it from anywhere.

However, when I try to put it on the main domain (domain.com) it doesn't work. When I try to access it trough Chrome, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Also, I am seeing this warning with regard to AAM in Logs:

```
Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://{computername}:24963 with the URL http://{domain.com}.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL http://{domain.com} as an AAM response URL.
```

I am sure that (domain.com) is added as an AAM. Also, I don't think this is a problem from the domain as we are able to host any regular application on the domain through IIS, but when it comes to SP site things are weird here.